# how can I scan data matrix barcode

Tags: ios6, ios7, xcode5

I want to scan data matrix codes, I tried zBar SDK, but it do not scan data matrix. is there any way to scan data matrix by using zBar or is there any other free libraries ?.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Apple API :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

A more complete answer is in this post : [Scanning barcode with AVCaptureMetadataOutput and AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300152/scanning-barcode-with-avcapturemetadataoutput-and-avfoundation)

Comment: The documentation states that the API is _Available in iOS 7.0 and later_ and further that the DataMatrixDecoding is only _Available in iOS 8.0 and later_. So this is neither a solution to get it done with iOS6 nor a solution to support iOS7.